# Image pushing divs below

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a 2 column layout with an image to the left and wanted to have 3 divs on the right but can only manage to get 1 div to align next to the image and the other 3 divs are below the image. How can I have all 3 divs next to the image?

I know this is easy with `grid-areas` but wanted to do it with out.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

.hero {
  background-color: red;
}

.foo {
  background-color: orange;
}

.bar {
  background-color: lime;
}

.baz {
  background-color: aqua;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hero">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    foo
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    bar
  </div>
  <div class="baz">
    baz
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/emmabbb/pen/oNqPwad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a specific grid row value on your hero: `grid-row: 1 / 4;`

Like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

.hero {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.foo {
  background-color: orange;
}

.bar {
  background-color: lime;
}

.baz {
  background-color: aqua;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hero">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    foo
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    bar
  </div>
  <div class="baz">
    baz
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want your divs with text in them to be of equal height change the grid template rows to `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` Like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.hero {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.foo {
  background-color: orange;
}

.bar {
  background-color: lime;
}

.baz {
  background-color: aqua;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hero">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    foo
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    bar
  </div>
  <div class="baz">
    baz
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to get the 3 divs on the right of the image without using grid area would be to **wrap foo, bar, and baz in a parent div and use 1 row on your grid**; you may have to mess with the hight of the divs on the right though.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="hero">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x1080" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="foo">
      foo
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
      bar
    </div>
    <div class="baz">
      baz
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that does what your looking for!